# What is the most efficient way of programming an output based on input (currently done with lots of if-statements)?

Tags: performance, comparison, microcontroller

In the microcontroller during operation `float output_value` will give me different values (control algorithm). I want to make use of some kind of "lookup table" in which I compare each value that I get from `float output_value` to find `float final_output_value`.

I have now a lot of if-statements such as:

```
if(output_value > 3.0 && output_value < 5.0)
{
 final_output_value = 3.2;
} 
if(output_value > 5.0 && output_value < 8.0)
{
 final_output_value = 5.7
}
```

So that is the idea. I am looking for a more efficient way, someone knows a better way?

Comment: How many different outcomes are there? Are we talking 5-10? 50-100? 500-1000? 10000?

Comment: around 300, in an MCU so I need fast performance

Comment: Well, I would implement different solutions and measure them, only way to be certain.

Comment: I would start by simplifying what you have: `if (output_value < 3.0) { ... } else if (output_value < 5.0) { ... } else if (output_value < 8.0) { ... } else if ...`. Then I would implement a table-driven solution with a binary search lookup, it *may* perform better but it isn't certain.

Comment: A simple test I did here indicates that with 300 such ranges, (all consecutive by the way), a table-driven binary search lookup method will be just shy of twice as fast. Note that careful arranging of the if-statements could cut that time down to even less than the table-driven approach but would be a nightmare to maintain. In essence you can write the table-driven approach using if-statements.

Comment: As I suspected, adding more if-statements to the code based approach will outperform the table driven approach that I implemented. For raw speed you should carefully lay out your if-statements. For maintainability you should go for a table-driven approach.

Comment: Can the conversion from `output` to `final_output` be approximated with a linear (or piece-wise linear) equation?  That would be pretty quick.

Comment: @RussSchultz That is also a very good way of solving it, I'll definitely check that out as well ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many deciding factors here that you don't mention so let me outline a few:

- Maintainability (ie. how easy is it to both get the code right and also to maintain it)
- Volatility (ie. how often does the range values and their outputs change?)
- Code size (you mention a micro controller scenario, do you have limitations on the size of your code that you need to overcome?)

An additional question I have that may change the advice I give (I say this because I only tested one variant, I don't know the effect of the other) is whether it is possible to optimize the range checks.

You have these two:

```
3.0 < v < 5.0
5.0 < v < 8.0
```

**But what about 5.0 *exactly***?

Can you rewrite the ranges like this:

```
3.0 <= v < 5.0
5.0 <= v < 8.0
```

(or put the equal sign on the other), so that the ranges are consecutive without holes between? I assumed yes, you can.

In any case, what I did was:

1. Write a pure "linear" code based set of if-statements, 300 of them
2. Write a table-driven approach that built a table by calling the method from point 1, once, and then reusing the table for a binary search on each lookoup
3. Write a slightly better version of the code-based approach from point 1.

Basically, the "linear" code approach looked like this:

```
private double IfStatementLookup(double input)
{
    if (input < 01.0) return 01.0;
    if (input < 02.0) return 02.0;
    if (input < 03.0) return 03.0;
    if (input < 04.0) return 04.0;
    if (input < 05.0) return 05.0;
```

and so on up to `< 300`, basically a simple "ceiling" function for a set of values. So `0 <= input < 1` returns `1`, and so on.

The table-driven approach looks like this:

```
private double TableLookup(double input)
{
    if (input >= 300)
        return 0;

    int lower = 0;
    int upper = _Table.Length - 1;

    while (lower <= upper)
    {
        int middle = lower + (upper - lower) / 2;
        if (input < _Table[middle][0])
            upper = middle - 1;
        else
            lower = middle + 1;
    }

    return _Table[upper][1];
}
```

And the slightly better version of the if-statements looks like this:

```
double SlightlyOptimizedIfStatementLookup(double input)
{
    if (input < 100)
    {
        if (input < 50)
        {
            if (input < 01.0) return 01.0;
            if (input < 02.0) return 02.0;
            if (input < 03.0) return 03.0;
        }
        // if-statements for 50-100
    }
    if (input < 200)
        // same here for 200-299
    if (input < 300)
        // same here for 300-399
```

Now, here are some bulletpoints before I show the benchmark results:

1. The if-statement approach will likely require more *code* than the table-driven approach, so you need to consider if this is at all important
2. Further changes to the slightly better if-statement version could be done, by roughly halving the range for each new level of if-statements, for instance by adding if-statements for `< 25` and `< 75` and so on inside the respective levels
3. The if-statement approach (either one) is not runtime maintainable. You can't load in a table of ranges from a file dynamically, or maintain via a user interface or a download such a table, you will need to release a new version of the software to change it.
4. Further optimizations could also probably be done to the table-driven approach.

The entire [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program can be found at the bottom of this answer. Be sure to run it with optimizations turned on (small `/o+` button bottom right).

**CAVEAT!** I might have made any number of mistakes in the program which have the potential to invalidate my entire answer. Please verify independently the results.

In any case, here are the benchmark results abbreviated:

```
                        Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
------------------------------ |----------:|----------:|----------:|
                   TableDriven | 163.95 us | 0.9125 us | 0.7620 us |
            LinearIfStatements | 314.41 us | 2.3511 us | 2.0842 us |
 SlightlyOptimizedIfStatements |  64.43 us | 0.7900 us | 0.7390 us |
```

**CONCLUSION**: A code-based if-statement based approach outperforms (my simple) table driven approach.

Here is the entire program, be aware that due to the number of if-statements it is kinda long.

```
void Main()
{
    new LookupTest().Validate();
    BenchmarkRunner.Run<LookupTest>();
}

public class LookupTest
{
    public LookupTest()
    {
        _Inputs = Enumerable.Range(0, 3000).Select(idx => idx / 10.0).ToArray();
        _Table = _Inputs.Select(input => new[] { input, IfStatementLookup(input) }).ToArray();

        TableDriven();
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        bool anyMismatch = false;
        foreach (var input in _Inputs)
        {
            var ifStatements = IfStatementLookup(input);
            var slightlyOptimizedIfStatements = SlightlyOptimizedIfStatementLookup(input);
            var tableDriven = TableLookup(input);

            if (ifStatements != tableDriven || ifStatements != slightlyOptimizedIfStatements)
            {
                $"{input:0.00} => if: {ifStatements}, lookup: {tableDriven}, if+: {slightlyOptimizedIfStatements}".Dump();
                anyMismatch = true;
            }
        }
        if (anyMismatch)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    private double[] _Inputs;
    private double[][] _Table;

    [Benchmark]
    public void TableDriven()
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < _Inputs.Length; index++)
        {
            sum += TableLookup(_Inputs[index]);
        }
        if (sum < 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    private double TableLookup(double input)
    {
        if (input >= 300)
            return 0;

        int lower = 0;
        int upper = _Table.Length - 1;

        while (lower <= upper)
        {
            int middle = lower + (upper - lower) / 2;
            if (input < _Table[middle][0])
                upper = middle - 1;
            else
                lower = middle + 1;
        }

        return _Table[upper][1];
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void LinearIfStatements()
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < _Inputs.Length; index++)
        {
            sum += IfStatementLookup(_Inputs[index]);
        }
        if (sum < 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void SlightlyOptimizedIfStatements()
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < _Inputs.Length; index++)
        {
            sum += SlightlyOptimizedIfStatementLookup(_Inputs[index]);
        }
        if (sum < 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    private double IfStatementLookup(double input)
    {
        if (input < 01.0) return 01.0;
        if (input < 02.0) return 02.0;
        if (input < 03.0) return 03.0;
        if (input < 04.0) return 04.0;
        if (input < 05.0) return 05.0;
        if (input < 06.0) return 06.0;
        if (input < 07.0) return 07.0;
        if (input < 08.0) return 08.0;
        if (input < 09.0) return 09.0;
        if (input < 10.0) return 10.0;
        if (input < 11.0) return 11.0;
        if (input < 12.0) return 12.0;
        if (input < 13.0) return 13.0;
        if (input < 14.0) return 14.0;
        if (input < 15.0) return 15.0;
        if (input < 16.0) return 16.0;
        if (input < 17.0) return 17.0;
        if (input < 18.0) return 18.0;
        if (input < 19.0) return 19.0;
        if (input < 20.0) return 20.0;
        if (input < 21.0) return 21.0;
        if (input < 22.0) return 22.0;
        if (input < 23.0) return 23.0;
        if (input < 24.0) return 24.0;
        if (input < 25.0) return 25.0;
        if (input < 26.0) return 26.0;
        if (input < 27.0) return 27.0;
        if (input < 28.0) return 28.0;
        if (input < 29.0) return 29.0;
        if (input < 30.0) return 30.0;
        if (input < 31.0) return 31.0;
        if (input < 32.0) return 32.0;
        if (input < 33.0) return 33.0;
        if (input < 34.0) return 34.0;
        if (input < 35.0) return 35.0;
        if (input < 36.0) return 36.0;
        if (input < 37.0) return 37.0;
        if (input < 38.0) return 38.0;
        if (input < 39.0) return 39.0;
        if (input < 40.0) return 40.0;
        if (input < 41.0) return 41.0;
        if (input < 42.0) return 42.0;
        if (input < 43.0) return 43.0;
        if (input < 44.0) return 44.0;
        if (input < 45.0) return 45.0;
        if (input < 46.0) return 46.0;
        if (input < 47.0) return 47.0;
        if (input < 48.0) return 48.0;
        if (input < 49.0) return 49.0;
        if (input < 50.0) return 50.0;
        if (input < 51.0) return 51.0;
        if (input < 52.0) return 52.0;
        if (input < 53.0) return 53.0;
        if (input < 54.0) return 54.0;
        if (input < 55.0) return 55.0;
        if (input < 56.0) return 56.0;
        if (input < 57.0) return 57.0;
        if (input < 58.0) return 58.0;
        if (input < 59.0) return 59.0;
        if (input < 60.0) return 60.0;
        if (input < 61.0) return 61.0;
        if (input < 62.0) return 62.0;
        if (input < 63.0) return 63.0;
        if (input < 64.0) return 64.0;
        if (input < 65.0) return 65.0;
        if (input < 66.0) return 66.0;
        if (input < 67.0) return 67.0;
        if (input < 68.0) return 68.0;
        if (input < 69.0) return 69.0;
        if (input < 70.0) return 70.0;
        if (input < 71.0) return 71.0;
        if (input < 72.0) return 72.0;
        if (input < 73.0) return 73.0;
        if (input < 74.0) return 74.0;
        if (input < 75.0) return 75.0;
        if (input < 76.0) return 76.0;
        if (input < 77.0) return 77.0;
        if (input < 78.0) return 78.0;
        if (input < 79.0) return 79.0;
        if (input < 80.0) return 80.0;
        if (input < 81.0) return 81.0;
        if (input < 82.0) return 82.0;
        if (input < 83.0) return 83.0;
        if (input < 84.0) return 84.0;
        if (input < 85.0) return 85.0;
        if (input < 86.0) return 86.0;
        if (input < 87.0) return 87.0;
        if (input < 88.0) return 88.0;
        if (input < 89.0) return 89.0;
        if (input < 90.0) return 90.0;
        if (input < 91.0) return 91.0;
        if (input < 92.0) return 92.0;
        if (input < 93.0) return 93.0;
        if (input < 94.0) return 94.0;
        if (input < 95.0) return 95.0;
        if (input < 96.0) return 96.0;
        if (input < 97.0) return 97.0;
        if (input < 98.0) return 98.0;
        if (input < 99.0) return 99.0;
        if (input < 100.0) return 100.0;
        if (input < 101.0) return 101.0;
        if (input < 102.0) return 102.0;
        if (input < 103.0) return 103.0;
        if (input < 104.0) return 104.0;
        if (input < 105.0) return 105.0;
        if (input < 106.0) return 106.0;
        if (input < 107.0) return 107.0;
        if (input < 108.0) return 108.0;
        if (input < 109.0) return 109.0;
        if (input < 110.0) return 110.0;
        if (input < 111.0) return 111.0;
        if (input < 112.0) return 112.0;
        if (input < 113.0) return 113.0;
        if (input < 114.0) return 114.0;
        if (input < 115.0) return 115.0;
        if (input < 116.0) return 116.0;
        if (input < 117.0) return 117.0;
        if (input < 118.0) return 118.0;
        if (input < 119.0) return 119.0;
        if (input < 120.0) return 120.0;
        if (input < 121.0) return 121.0;
        if (input < 122.0) return 122.0;
        if (input < 123.0) return 123.0;
        if (input < 124.0) return 124.0;
        if (input < 125.0) return 125.0;
        if (input < 126.0) return 126.0;
        if (input < 127.0) return 127.0;
        if (input < 128.0) return 128.0;
        if (input < 129.0) return 129.0;
        if (input < 130.0) return 130.0;
        if (input < 131.0) return 131.0;
        if (input < 132.0) return 132.0;
        if (input < 133.0) return 133.0;
        if (input < 134.0) return 134.0;
        if (input < 135.0) return 135.0;
        if (input < 136.0) return 136.0;
        if (input < 137.0) return 137.0;
        if (input < 138.0) return 138.0;
        if (input < 139.0) return 139.0;
        if (input < 140.0) return 140.0;
        if (input < 141.0) return 141.0;
        if (input < 142.0) return 142.0;
        if (input < 143.0) return 143.0;
        if (input < 144.0) return 144.0;
        if (input < 145.0) return 145.0;
        if (input < 146.0) return 146.0;
        if (input < 147.0) return 147.0;
        if (input < 148.0) return 148.0;
        if (input < 149.0) return 149.0;
        if (input < 150.0) return 150.0;
        if (input < 151.0) return 151.0;
        if (input < 152.0) return 152.0;
        if (input < 153.0) return 153.0;
        if (input < 154.0) return 154.0;
        if (input < 155.0) return 155.0;
        if (input < 156.0) return 156.0;
        if (input < 157.0) return 157.0;
        if (input < 158.0) return 158.0;
        if (input < 159.0) return 159.0;
        if (input < 160.0) return 160.0;
        if (input < 161.0) return 161.0;
        if (input < 162.0) return 162.0;
        if (input < 163.0) return 163.0;
        if (input < 164.0) return 164.0;
        if (input < 165.0) return 165.0;
        if (input < 166.0) return 166.0;
        if (input < 167.0) return 167.0;
        if (input < 168.0) return 168.0;
        if (input < 169.0) return 169.0;
        if (input < 170.0) return 170.0;
        if (input < 171.0) return 171.0;
        if (input < 172.0) return 172.0;
        if (input < 173.0) return 173.0;
        if (input < 174.0) return 174.0;
        if (input < 175.0) return 175.0;
        if (input < 176.0) return 176.0;
        if (input < 177.0) return 177.0;
        if (input < 178.0) return 178.0;
        if (input < 179.0) return 179.0;
        if (input < 180.0) return 180.0;
        if (input < 181.0) return 181.0;
        if (input < 182.0) return 182.0;
        if (input < 183.0) return 183.0;
        if (input < 184.0) return 184.0;
        if (input < 185.0) return 185.0;
        if (input < 186.0) return 186.0;
        if (input < 187.0) return 187.0;
        if (input < 188.0) return 188.0;
        if (input < 189.0) return 189.0;
        if (input < 190.0) return 190.0;
        if (input < 191.0) return 191.0;
        if (input < 192.0) return 192.0;
        if (input < 193.0) return 193.0;
        if (input < 194.0) return 194.0;
        if (input < 195.0) return 195.0;
        if (input < 196.0) return 196.0;
        if (input < 197.0) return 197.0;
        if (input < 198.0) return 198.0;
        if (input < 199.0) return 199.0;

        # error Stack Overflow limited my answer
        // Copy the 200-299-block above and just
        // Alt+Shift Selection to mark the 2's and change them to 3's
        // BOTH PLACES

        return 0;
    }

    double SlightlyOptimizedIfStatementLookup(double input)
    {
        if (input < 100)
        {
            if (input < 50)
            {
                if (input < 01.0) return 01.0;
                if (input < 02.0) return 02.0;
                if (input < 03.0) return 03.0;
                if (input < 04.0) return 04.0;
                if (input < 05.0) return 05.0;
                if (input < 06.0) return 06.0;
                if (input < 07.0) return 07.0;
                if (input < 08.0) return 08.0;
                if (input < 09.0) return 09.0;
                if (input < 10.0) return 10.0;
                if (input < 11.0) return 11.0;
                if (input < 12.0) return 12.0;
                if (input < 13.0) return 13.0;
                if (input < 14.0) return 14.0;
                if (input < 15.0) return 15.0;
                if (input < 16.0) return 16.0;
                if (input < 17.0) return 17.0;
                if (input < 18.0) return 18.0;
                if (input < 19.0) return 19.0;
                if (input < 20.0) return 20.0;
                if (input < 21.0) return 21.0;
                if (input < 22.0) return 22.0;
                if (input < 23.0) return 23.0;
                if (input < 24.0) return 24.0;
                if (input < 25.0) return 25.0;
                if (input < 26.0) return 26.0;
                if (input < 27.0) return 27.0;
                if (input < 28.0) return 28.0;
                if (input < 29.0) return 29.0;
                if (input < 30.0) return 30.0;
                if (input < 31.0) return 31.0;
                if (input < 32.0) return 32.0;
                if (input < 33.0) return 33.0;
                if (input < 34.0) return 34.0;
                if (input < 35.0) return 35.0;
                if (input < 36.0) return 36.0;
                if (input < 37.0) return 37.0;
                if (input < 38.0) return 38.0;
                if (input < 39.0) return 39.0;
                if (input < 40.0) return 40.0;
                if (input < 41.0) return 41.0;
                if (input < 42.0) return 42.0;
                if (input < 43.0) return 43.0;
                if (input < 44.0) return 44.0;
                if (input < 45.0) return 45.0;
                if (input < 46.0) return 46.0;
                if (input < 47.0) return 47.0;
                if (input < 48.0) return 48.0;
                if (input < 49.0) return 49.0;
                return 50.0;
            }

            if (input < 51.0) return 51.0;
            if (input < 52.0) return 52.0;
            if (input < 53.0) return 53.0;
            if (input < 54.0) return 54.0;
            if (input < 55.0) return 55.0;
            if (input < 56.0) return 56.0;
            if (input < 57.0) return 57.0;
            if (input < 58.0) return 58.0;
            if (input < 59.0) return 59.0;
            if (input < 60.0) return 60.0;
            if (input < 61.0) return 61.0;
            if (input < 62.0) return 62.0;
            if (input < 63.0) return 63.0;
            if (input < 64.0) return 64.0;
            if (input < 65.0) return 65.0;
            if (input < 66.0) return 66.0;
            if (input < 67.0) return 67.0;
            if (input < 68.0) return 68.0;
            if (input < 69.0) return 69.0;
            if (input < 70.0) return 70.0;
            if (input < 71.0) return 71.0;
            if (input < 72.0) return 72.0;
            if (input < 73.0) return 73.0;
            if (input < 74.0) return 74.0;
            if (input < 75.0) return 75.0;
            if (input < 76.0) return 76.0;
            if (input < 77.0) return 77.0;
            if (input < 78.0) return 78.0;
            if (input < 79.0) return 79.0;
            if (input < 80.0) return 80.0;
            if (input < 81.0) return 81.0;
            if (input < 82.0) return 82.0;
            if (input < 83.0) return 83.0;
            if (input < 84.0) return 84.0;
            if (input < 85.0) return 85.0;
            if (input < 86.0) return 86.0;
            if (input < 87.0) return 87.0;
            if (input < 88.0) return 88.0;
            if (input < 89.0) return 89.0;
            if (input < 90.0) return 90.0;
            if (input < 91.0) return 91.0;
            if (input < 92.0) return 92.0;
            if (input < 93.0) return 93.0;
            if (input < 94.0) return 94.0;
            if (input < 95.0) return 95.0;
            if (input < 96.0) return 96.0;
            if (input < 97.0) return 97.0;
            if (input < 98.0) return 98.0;
            if (input < 99.0) return 99.0;
            return 100.0;
        }
        if (input < 200)
        {
            if (input < 150)
            {
                if (input < 101.0) return 101.0;
                if (input < 102.0) return 102.0;
                if (input < 103.0) return 103.0;
                if (input < 104.0) return 104.0;
                if (input < 105.0) return 105.0;
                if (input < 106.0) return 106.0;
                if (input < 107.0) return 107.0;
                if (input < 108.0) return 108.0;
                if (input < 109.0) return 109.0;
                if (input < 110.0) return 110.0;
                if (input < 111.0) return 111.0;
                if (input < 112.0) return 112.0;
                if (input < 113.0) return 113.0;
                if (input < 114.0) return 114.0;
                if (input < 115.0) return 115.0;
                if (input < 116.0) return 116.0;
                if (input < 117.0) return 117.0;
                if (input < 118.0) return 118.0;
                if (input < 119.0) return 119.0;
                if (input < 120.0) return 120.0;
                if (input < 121.0) return 121.0;
                if (input < 122.0) return 122.0;
                if (input < 123.0) return 123.0;
                if (input < 124.0) return 124.0;
                if (input < 125.0) return 125.0;
                if (input < 126.0) return 126.0;
                if (input < 127.0) return 127.0;
                if (input < 128.0) return 128.0;
                if (input < 129.0) return 129.0;
                if (input < 130.0) return 130.0;
                if (input < 131.0) return 131.0;
                if (input < 132.0) return 132.0;
                if (input < 133.0) return 133.0;
                if (input < 134.0) return 134.0;
                if (input < 135.0) return 135.0;
                if (input < 136.0) return 136.0;
                if (input < 137.0) return 137.0;
                if (input < 138.0) return 138.0;
                if (input < 139.0) return 139.0;
                if (input < 140.0) return 140.0;
                if (input < 141.0) return 141.0;
                if (input < 142.0) return 142.0;
                if (input < 143.0) return 143.0;
                if (input < 144.0) return 144.0;
                if (input < 145.0) return 145.0;
                if (input < 146.0) return 146.0;
                if (input < 147.0) return 147.0;
                if (input < 148.0) return 148.0;
                if (input < 149.0) return 149.0;
                return 150.0;
            }
            if (input < 151.0) return 151.0;
            if (input < 152.0) return 152.0;
            if (input < 153.0) return 153.0;
            if (input < 154.0) return 154.0;
            if (input < 155.0) return 155.0;
            if (input < 156.0) return 156.0;
            if (input < 157.0) return 157.0;
            if (input < 158.0) return 158.0;
            if (input < 159.0) return 159.0;
            if (input < 160.0) return 160.0;
            if (input < 161.0) return 161.0;
            if (input < 162.0) return 162.0;
            if (input < 163.0) return 163.0;
            if (input < 164.0) return 164.0;
            if (input < 165.0) return 165.0;
            if (input < 166.0) return 166.0;
            if (input < 167.0) return 167.0;
            if (input < 168.0) return 168.0;
            if (input < 169.0) return 169.0;
            if (input < 170.0) return 170.0;
            if (input < 171.0) return 171.0;
            if (input < 172.0) return 172.0;
            if (input < 173.0) return 173.0;
            if (input < 174.0) return 174.0;
            if (input < 175.0) return 175.0;
            if (input < 176.0) return 176.0;
            if (input < 177.0) return 177.0;
            if (input < 178.0) return 178.0;
            if (input < 179.0) return 179.0;
            if (input < 180.0) return 180.0;
            if (input < 181.0) return 181.0;
            if (input < 182.0) return 182.0;
            if (input < 183.0) return 183.0;
            if (input < 184.0) return 184.0;
            if (input < 185.0) return 185.0;
            if (input < 186.0) return 186.0;
            if (input < 187.0) return 187.0;
            if (input < 188.0) return 188.0;
            if (input < 189.0) return 189.0;
            if (input < 190.0) return 190.0;
            if (input < 191.0) return 191.0;
            if (input < 192.0) return 192.0;
            if (input < 193.0) return 193.0;
            if (input < 194.0) return 194.0;
            if (input < 195.0) return 195.0;
            if (input < 196.0) return 196.0;
            if (input < 197.0) return 197.0;
            if (input < 198.0) return 198.0;
            if (input < 199.0) return 199.0;
            return 200.0;
        }
        if (input < 300)
        {
            # error Stack Overflow limited my answer
            // Copy the 200-block above and just
            // Alt+Shift Selection to mark the 2's and change them to 3's
            // BOTH PLACES
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Due to Stack Overflow have a limit of 30.000 characters for an answer I had to cut short the program above. You can find a download of the complete LINQPad script [here](https://gist.github.com/lassevk/985179c6f3c56a08cd30b2ab0e0815cd).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is a great answer indeed.

Comment: The lookup table created this way is unnecessarily large (10x larger than needed), since many elements map to the same rounded value (there are 300 `if`s, there is no need to have `3000` table entries). But even after [changing the table to contain 300 elements](https://gist.github.com/vgrudenic/ac3da32501a9defc552c6d8aa34c8d47), and randomizing inputs, the difference between `TableLookup` and `SlightlyOptimizedIfStatementLookup` reduced only a bit, although the latter still wins (lookup is ~2x faster, optimized if is ~3x faster than reference). Perhaps I did something wrong too, of course.